# Error Fatal error: Class 'Oauth' not found when using OAuth

Tags: php, oauth

I using code demo from link 
[http://djpate.com](http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/)

When I run `http://localhost:8080/test/OAuthProviderExample/client/index.php` is it get error `Fatal error: Class 'Oauth' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\OAuthProviderExample\client\index.php on line 2`

in client/index.php i using:

```
$oauth_client = new Oauth("key","secret"); // line 2
$oauth_client->enableDebug();
```

How to fix it, i using wampserver in windows 7

Comment: That error means you don't have the class in your file structure. It needs to be included with `include('path/to/oauth.php');`

Comment: @Jon: I using windows OS, how to find library for oauth

Comment: @HaiTruongIT Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Rathinam: yes, this issue has been solved

Answer (score 1):

remember there's one step in the tutorial:

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

This is installing the oauth lib, in Windows OS it should be "oauth.dll" liked file, check where to get the lib file for Windows. and see if the problem solved.

Comment: check here please, http://downloads.php.net/pierre/             try php_oauth-1.1.1-dev-5.3-vc9-x86.zip

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I think wamp installs using win32 bits by default. Even if you are running windows 64bit OS. So download the 86x version here  [For PHP version 5.5](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/php_oauth-1.2.3-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip) .
Extract the Zip file and copy the php_oauth.dll found in your extract to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext` Click on your wamp server, goto **PHP**`>`**php.ini**, add this`extension=php_oauth.dll` to a place where you find similar text or anywhere. Now exit your wamp server. Start it up again and in **PHP**`>`**PHP extensions** you should see php_oauth ticked. However, if you still encounter problems goto PHP error logto get a clue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Oauth for PHP 5.4 Windows x86**

PHP/5.4.7
http://zahymaka.com/314/php-5-4-oauth-x86-windows

This is not my source so im not sure how stable ,but it was the only option I've found after about an hour and a half of searching.

Throw the file into your php/ext folder

Edit your php.ini to include the extension

extension=php_oauth.dll